# Can I pass parameters to multiple notebooks in a Synapse pipeline?

Tags: azure-synapse

I have a Synapse pipeline with 10 notebooks executed in sequence. These notebooks take various parameters, some of which are common to all or a few of the notebooks. Rather than define the value of these parameters for each notebook (which is repetitive) I wonder can I define them once at the pipeline level and pass them into each notebook that uses them?

So far I tried defining one of the parameters at the pipeline level `myparam` with a default value and then in the notebook parameters I reference the pipeline parameter as `@pipeline().parameter.myparam` which I thought would take the default value defined at the pipeline level - but it doesn't. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass parameters to multiple notebooks in a Synapse pipeline.

As per this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-expression-language-functions),

> You can use parameters to pass external values into pipelines,
> datasets, linked services, and data flows. Once the parameter has been
> passed into the resource, it cannot be changed. **By parameterizing
> resources, you can reuse them with different values each time.**
> Parameters can be used individually or as a part of expressions. JSON
> values in the definition can be literal or expressions that are
> evaluated at runtime.

Below are some referred Parameters example which might help you.

[image]

Comment: How can I define a parameter for the pipeline say 'my_parameter' that then is either passed to the Notebook itself or to the Notebook parameters? I'm thinking it isn't possible at this stage.

Comment: refer and learn from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pISBgwrdxPM&ab_channel=AdamMarczak-AzureforEveryone